# Problem using XPM to edit image

Tags: experience-manager, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

I have a Schema which contains an image and multiple other values. I am trying to make XPM work so that this image can be changed by editors.

The image is loaded as follows inside of the view:

```
<div ${markup.entity(entity)}>
        <a href="${entity.link.url}">
            <div ${markup.property(entity, "image")}>
                <dxa:media media="${entity.image}" />
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
```

Changing the image inside XPM results in an Internal Server Error for the editor.

On the console the following error is printed:

```
18:25:00.803 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /index-toerisme.html
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "v0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.linking.AbstractTridionLinkResolver.resolveLink(AbstractTridionLinkResolver.java:66) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.linking.AbstractTridionLinkResolver.resolveLink(AbstractTridionLinkResolver.java:35) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.linking.AbstractTridionLinkResolver.resolveLink(AbstractTridionLinkResolver.java:28) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.converters.ComponentLinkFieldConverter.createComponentLink(ComponentLinkFieldConverter.java:109) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl$ComponentEntity.createLink(SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.java:274) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.getSelfFieldData(SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.java:162) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:161) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:547) ~[spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:102) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:298) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:259) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipeline.java:88) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.PageBuilderImpl$DD4TRegionBuilderCallback.buildEntity(PageBuilderImpl.java:623) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder.buildRegions(DefaultRegionBuilder.java:46) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.PageBuilderImpl.createPage(PageBuilderImpl.java:257) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.createPageModel(ModelBuilderPipeline.java:72) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider$1.tryFindPage(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:287) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider$1.tryFindPage(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:267) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider.findPage(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:102) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider.getPageModel(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:267) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:342) ~[dxa-common-api-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:124) ~[dxa-common-api-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:286) [web-ambient-client-8.2.0-1005.jar:8.2.0-1005]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Editing String values using XPM works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's directly related to the image, but the error looks like the web app is trying to resolve a link to a versioned ID. You've probably got the versioned ID because of session preview publishing a minor version. Maybe you need to strip the -v0 in code before trying to resolve the link?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting... indeed, the problem seems to be that you get a `-v0` TCM URI of a Component to be resolved and `AbstractTridionLinkResolver` contains very primitive TCM URI parsing logic, which tries to interpret the `v0` as an (integer) item type.

I'm not sure why we didn't encounter this defect earlier in our testing (we do have quite some XPM test cases), but it looks like a DXA defect to me. Can you report this issue in GitHub?  https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues

I'm afraid that you will have to change the LinkResolver implementation to fix this issue (if you do so, please submit a Pull Request).

Comment: did this ever get fixed - I just saw the same behaviour in a DXA Java 1.7 app

Comment: I dont think so, as I see in the code that it still expects an integer. I made an issue for it: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/78